# Error starting npm on new computer

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Im new with node/npm/webpack. I have a project on my Macbook that works perfectly but when I copied all the files to my pc (Windows 10) Im not sure why I can't start it.

What I did:

1- Copy all the files.

2- Install Node

3- `npm install`

4- `npm i webpack-dev-server -g`

5- `rm node_modules` and reinstall with `npm install`

The first error was about webpack-dev-server but seems to work now because localhost opens.

I think Im missing some important step to make all work on this PC.
The last log when I run `npm run prod` is this:

[PasteBin debug.log](https://pastebin.com/Rv0hnfnb)

[PasteBin package.json](https://pastebin.com/iEbLTyBf)

If you have some tips to write better questions please tell me how to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an environment variable, like `NODE_ENV=production`, does not work on Windows and it will result in an error. On Windows the command would be:

```
set NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p
```

Instead of having to define two separate scripts to make it work on different platforms, you can use [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env). Install the package from npm.

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

And add `cross-env` in front of the environment variables:

```
"prod": "npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `"prod": "npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",` but `npm run prod` and `npm run dev` still not working.

Now I can't even see an error with `npm run prod`
https://pastebin.com/Wd0vhLhs

Comment: With `npm run dev` I get `Error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'`
so I tried to delete npm cache and reinstall again all dependencies deleting node_modules and `npm install` again. Didnt fix it. Ty

Comment: There is no error, but you're not executing webpack. `set NODE_ENV=production webpack -p` is not the same as the Unix version (without the set). You need the `&&` to separate the commands. Or use the much better `cross-env` version (which you didn't try, according to the log).

Comment: You don't have `underscore` in your `package.json` as a dependency, so it won't be installed. You need to add it `npm install --save underscore`. You probably forgot to use the `--save` option on your other machine, which only installed it without adding it to the `package.json` (This behaviour has been changed with npm v5, and `--save` is the default).

Comment: Im totally lost. I didn't remember to install underscore when I did the project and now it says that can't find is-my-json-valid which I didn't use in the project neither.
Im getting an error almost each command I write :(

Comment: btw I don't know what to do exactly with this 
https://pastebin.com/v56vCthg
when I install cross-env

Comment: could it be something with relative paths or something like that? I mean, it is asking me to install a lot of modules that I never had to install on MacOS. Maybe they are there but can't find them. No idea what step take now. Btw thanks for your time